# Why is $3^{n+1} = 3^n + 2\cdot 3^n$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I don't see how this equation holds true
$3^{n+1} = 3^n + 2\cdot 3^n$ especially when there is a $2\cdot 3^n$ on the right equation.

Comment: $3^n+2\cdot 3^n=3^n(1+2)=3^n\cdot 3=3^{n+1}$.

Comment: odd+even=odd. So why do you think it is impossible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three $3^n$s make one $3^{n+1}$.  The rhs is sum of $x$ and $y$ where $x$ is single $3^n$ and $y$ is two $3^n$s.

Same way you can see, e.g., $7^{n+1} = 7^n + 6\cdot 7^n$

Comment: This is a much better explanation than my own.

Comment: @mweiss: it's all the same as yours; just wordings are a bit different.

Comment: They're mathematically equivalent of course -- it's hard to imagine an answer that *wouldn't* be --  but I think yours is a better *explanation* precisely because it uses words ("three", "two") instead of numerals. Conceptually your explanation treats $3^n$ as a noun, and the other quantities as adjectives. Mine operates only at the level of symbolic manipulation.

Comment: I do frequently use this  approach deliberately when I feel the question is from a learner. Thanks for showing appreciation. In another post yesterday my attempt in a similar vein was not appreciated much.

Comment: I understand it now. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 4):

The trick to recognizing these as equal is to write $3^n$ as $1 \cdot 3^n$.  Then you can factor the right-hand side:
$$1 \cdot 3^n + 2 \cdot 3^n = (1+2)3^n$$
From there it's pretty straightforward.

Comment: This somehow manages to contain even less useful information than mathlove's comment :/

Comment: @MagicMan You think so? I thought it highlighted what might make the problem hard for the OP (not seeing the unwritten factor of 1) without giving away the entire solution.

Comment: Perhaps OP will find it useful--I was just surprised to see an incomplete answer for this question in light of mathlove's comment.

Comment: Well, I may be projecting onto the OP, but I would expect that a questioner who would have trouble with this identity might also have trouble making sense of a chain of three equations, as in mathlove's comment.  Not everybody knows how to read and interpret those.

Comment: That's fair. Regardless, hopefully OP knows why the equation is true now. :)

Answer (score 0):

$$ 3^{n+1}=3^{n}\cdot3$$ 
But here is the trick, we can add zero $$0=-3^{n}+3^{n}$$ on the right hand side and afterwards rearrange it:
$$3^{n}\cdot3=3^{n}\cdot3+0= $$
$$3^{n}\cdot3-3^{n}+3^{n}=$$
$$2\cdot3^{n}+3^{n} $$